# Two requests from different threads with different urls in same httpclient instance

Tags: c#, httpclient

I make two different 'GET' requests from two different threads at the same time.
Will i have any conflicts if i will try to send at the same time but with different urls?

```
 static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 private void Thread1()
 {
   var result= await client.GetAsync("http://URL1");
 }

 private void Thread2()
 {
   var result= await client.GetAsync("http://URL2");
 }
```

Methods Thread1 and Thread2 will run at the same time. Will i have any problem? Or httpclient will handle both requests fine?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: So the short answer?

Comment: That was the short answer ;p `Properties of HttpClient should not be modified while there are outstanding requests, because it is not thread-safe.
(...) The following methods are thread safe: (...) 3. GetAsync`

Comment: Thank you Nilsk. So in my case HttpClient will handle the requests at the same time fine! Right?

Comment: That is indeed what the docs say, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll work fine, [just like the docs say it will](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#remarks).